# My Ink Manager user control can save a signature, but not via the app bar save button

Tags: c#, xaml, winrt-xaml

I am new to Win RT, so I am using a MSDN reference for my Signature Control, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn792131.aspx
In this code I can save the signature via a save button within the User Control. But I want to save the signature via a Save button in the App Bar, outside of the User Control.
The problem is that I cannot work out how to bind a user control with a canvass control to the view model I need to save the signature.
In my ViewModel I am using Prism to save the data;

```
public SurveyPageViewModel(INavigationService navigationService, ISurveyRepository surveyRepository, ILoggedOnUser loggedOnUser, IEventAggregator eventAggregator, IAppdispatcher appdispatcher, IAppState state)
{
    NavService = navigationService;
    SurvRepository = surveyRepository;
    CurrentLoggedOnUser = loggedOnUser;
    EventAgg = eventAggregator;
    AppDis = appdispatcher;
    State = state;

    CancelExitCommand = new DelegateCommand(DoCancelExit);
    SaveAndExitCommand = new DelegateCommand(DoSaveAndExit);
    SaveCommand = new DelegateCommand(DoSave);
}
```

And in the DoSave method I try to save the Signature;

```
case AppQuestionType.Signature:
    var sign = this.Signature;
    sign.JobId = propertySurveyId;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SignatureFullNameOfPerson))
    {
        SurveyPageViewModel spPageViewModel;
        //var surveyRepository = M.Survey.UILogic.Repositoriesolve(typeof(ISurveyRepository)) as ISurveyRepository;
        //spPageViewModel.AddSignatureFileEntry(propertySurveyId, 
        //this.SignatureFilename,
        //this.SignatureFullNameOfPerson);
    }
```

(Commented out code are my attempts that do not work).

The User Control is as follows:

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="M.Survey.UserControls.SignUserControl1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:M.Survey.UserControls"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300" 
    xmlns:templateSelectors="using:M.Survey.TemplateSelectors"
    xmlns:converters="using:M.Survey.Converters" 
    xmlns:canvas="using:Microsoft.Graphics.Canvas.UI.Xaml"
    xmlns:viewModels="using:M.Survey.UILogic.ViewModels" Width="348">

    <UserControl.Resources>

        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/Themes/Styles.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/Themes/AllQuestionDataTemplates.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/Themes/DataTemplates.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

            <converters:BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter" />
            <converters:InverseBooleanConverter x:Key="InverseBooleanConverter" />
            <converters:InverseBooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="InverseBooleanToVisibilityConverter" />

            <templateSelectors:QuestionTemplateSelector x:Key="QuestionDisplay" Signature="{StaticResource Signature}" />
        </ResourceDictionary>

    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid >
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="95*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="79*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="54,21,0,247" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding SignatureFullNameOfPerson, Mode=TwoWay}" Width="273" RequestedTheme="Dark" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
            <TextBox.BorderBrush>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </TextBox.BorderBrush>
        </TextBox>
        <Grid Margin="41,-9,-32,0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="154*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="155*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="150*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="157*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="157*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="157*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <StackPanel Name="spHorizontal" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="31,10,-24,10" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="2" >
                <viewModels:InkCanvas  
                    x:Name="icSignature"  Width="268" Background="#FF8A8A8A"  Loaded="IcSignature_OnLoaded" Margin="0,98,0,0"  />

            </StackPanel>

            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="-33,165,65,-74" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Grid.RowSpan="1"  HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="307" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="4">
                <Button Content="Erase"      Width="135"  Margin="0,16,3,7" Click="erase_Click" Background="Black" Height="41"/>
                <Button Content="Save"      Width="163"  Margin="0,16,3,7" Background="Black" Click="Save_Click" Height="41" >

                </Button>
                <!--CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=icSignature}" Command="{Binding SaveSignatureQuestionCommand}"-->
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-140,21,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Name of person" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="135" Height="48" FontSize="15" Foreground="#FF211C1C"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Many Thanks

Comment: You have to add your user control to the page by adding it on xaml & then your user control's data context will be your view model. Hope it helps.

Comment: Many thanks for the reply. I am doing what you have suggested. But my problem is canvas ink strokes are not getting binded or inkstrokes instances are not coming to viewmodel. My objective is to store canvas as image file with the ink strokes in viewmodel. Can you suggest how to achieve this.  Many thanks